# Calculate speed of a moving object with cameras

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, tracking

Is it possible to find the speed or direction of ships that are moving by, using a camera mounted on another ship?

The information I know is the speed, heading (true north), roll, pitch, and camera parameters of the ship where the camera is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course calculate the speed and direction of objects in terms of pixels per frame.

To get speed values of the real object, you would however need to use something like calibrated stereo cameras to know the distance of the objects to the camera.

Once the distance of objects in the images is know, the parameters of the moving camera could be included into the calculation.